# Simplify with Assumptions: Puzzle for 4 variables

Tags: simplifying-expressions, assumptions

I have a rather specific question about `Simplify[]` (hope this is not off-topic).
The puzzle I have is that `Simplify[]` with `Assumption` work rather differently for 3 variables versus 4 variables with `Sqrt[]`. Here is a simple example that I found about simplifying $\Theta(\sqrt{x^2 -\sqrt{x^2 y^2 + z^2}})$:

```
Simplify[HeavisideTheta[Sqrt[x^2  -  Sqrt[x^2  y^2 + z^2]]], x^2 >  Sqrt[x^2  y^2 + z^2]]
```

returns 1 as one expect since the argument is by assumption positive.

Now simply multiply $w^2$ with $z^2$ in the expression in the second $\sqrt{\cdots \sqrt{x^2 y^2 + z^2}} \rightarrow \sqrt{\cdots \sqrt{x^2 y^2 + z^2 w^2}}$, using the code:

```
Simplify[HeavisideTheta[Sqrt[x^2 - Sqrt[x^2 y^2 + z^2  w^2]]], x^2 > Sqrt[x^2 y^2 + z^2  w^2]]
```

This doesn't simplify at all, even though it has exact same form as the first expression (so it's not due to the `Sqrt[]`).

Maybe there is something simple that I missed? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this is a bug. And if nobody comes up with an explanation you should report it to: support@wolfram.com

Comment: [`See`](https : // mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/212172/9362) `SetSystemOptions[
  "SimplificationOptions" -> "AssumptionsMaxNonlinearVariables" -> 10];` Then
`Simplify[HeavisideTheta[Sqrt[x^2 - Sqrt[x^2 y^2 + z^2 w^2]]], 
 x^2 > Sqrt[x^2 y^2 + z^2 w^2]]` evaluates to `1`

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks so much! This makes sense. I guess in general how do I check the systemOptions related to a function? It's not on Wolfram Reference as far as I see the page for Simplify[]

Comment: The `SystemOptions` are not options of the command `Simplify` so they are not documented there. They are lower level options used internally. See the documentation for `SystemOptions`. `SystemOptions[]` will give all options. You can pare this list using  a name or a partial name with wildcards, e.g.,  `SystemOptions["*Simpl*"]`